# New Registration for Multiple Participants NOT Working - End up in a empty page

Tags: civievent

I encounter a blank page when i try to register contacts for an event. Refer to step 3. Kindly advise what went wrong? or is there any settings that i missed out? [image]

[image]

[image]

This is what I see under the browser (Microsoft Edge) developer console.
How do I resolve the error ?

[image]

Comment: That's typical of a javascript error or an error that happened on the server during an ajax call. If you open the browser dev console and look on the console tab or the network tab you should see some errors. If it's the latter then you'll need to look in the web server logs to see the actual full error.